# Get session os user in an oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, session, triggers, oracle10g

I would like to extract the os user from the oracle session executing the command in an tables trigger. Is this possible and if so can anyone point me on how I can achieve this? Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_my_table_after_delete
AFTER DELETE
   ON my_table
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sync_my_table_audit
   ( 
     id,
     audit_user,
     audit_action,
     audit_date)
   VALUES
   ( :old.id,
     --executing session's os user,
     'D',
     current_timestamp );
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER')` is your friend, see [SYS_CONTEXT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117)